# SQL counting and summing records based on values in other columns and aggregating by week number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to measure my teams throughput in responding to queries. I need to sum up what has been raised in one week and closed in the same week. It is possible to close queries that have been raised last year as well and I want to log that in the week it has been closed.

I have a table below:

*note: when status = 3, it means it is "CLOSED" else "OPEN"

```
+---------+------+----------+----------+
|queryno_i|status|issue_date|mutation  |
+---------+------+----------+----------+
|102      |1     |02/01/2014|02/01/2014|
+---------+------+----------+----------+
|103      |2     |03/01/2014|03/01/2014|
+---------+------+----------+----------+
|104      |3     |05/01/2014|07/01/2014|
+---------+------+----------+----------+
|105      |3     |06/01/2014|08/01/2014|
+---------+------+----------+----------+
|106      |4     |08/01/2014|08/01/2014|
+---------+------+----------+----------+
|204      |3     |02/04/2013|08/01/2014|
+---------+------+----------+----------+
```

My desired result is:

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|Week Number|count_of_issued|count_of_closed|
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|1          |2              |0              |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|2          |3              |3              |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

I want to be able to count how many were queries were opened in a week and how many were closed in the same week.

Here is a sample of my code... but its output is not correct.

```
SELECT 
Week_Number,
SUM(cnt_closed) AS 'Closed', 
FROM
(
    select
        DATEPART(wk,issued_date) AS 'Week_Number',
        DATEPART(wk,mutation) AS 'week_closed',
        case /*count closed (else 0 so when we sum it will not affect our count)*/
            when 
                status = '3' then count(queryno_i)
            else '0'
        end as 'cnt_closed',
        issued_date as 'issued'
    from t.tech_query
    group by status, issued_date, mutation
) AS cnt
WHERE Week_Number <= DATEPART(wk,GETDATE()) OR week_closed <= DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())
GROUP BY issued, Week_Number, week_closed
ORDER BY issued DESC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two-part query. The best way to start is to break down your question into parts.

First, I want to see a count of all the tickets that were opened by week:

```
SELECT datepart(wk, issued_date) as week_number
     , count(queryno_i) as issued_requests
 FROM t.tech_query
 GROUP BY datepart(wk, issued_date)
```

And I also want to see all the tickets that were opened and closed in the same week

```
SELECT datepart(wk, issued_date) as week_number
     , count(queryno_i)
 FROM t.tech_query
where status=3
GROUP BY datepart(wk, issued_date)
```

Then, it should just be a matter of joining the results together.

```
WITH alltickets AS
(
    SELECT datepart(wk, issued_date) as week_number
         , count(queryno_i) as issued_requests
     FROM t.tech_query
     GROUP BY datepart(wk, issued_date)
), completedinsameweek AS
(
    SELECT datepart(wk, issued_date) as week_number
         , count(queryno_i) completed_requests
 FROM t.tech_query
    where status=3 and datepart(wk, issued_date) = datepart(wk, mutation_date)
    GROUP BY datepart(wk, issued_date)
)
SELECT alltickets.week_number
     , alltickets.issued_requests
     , completedinsameweek.completed_requests
FROM alltickets JOIN completedinsameweek
  ON (alltickets.week_number = completedinsameweek.week_number)
```

Note that completed tickets that were completed in a later week aren't counted in this query.

If you're just trying to determine the total count of opened and the count of closed for a given week, the query should be simpler:

```
WITH issuedtickets AS
(
    SELECT datepart(wk, issued_date) as week_number
         , count(queryno_i) as issued_requests
     FROM t.tech_query
     GROUP BY datepart(wk, issued_date)
), completedtickets AS
(
    SELECT datepart(wk, mutation_date) as week_number
         , count(queryno_i) completed_requests
 FROM t.tech_query
    where status=3
    GROUP BY datepart(wk, mutation_date)
)
SELECT issuedtickets.week_number
     , issuedtickets.issued_requests
     , completedtickets.completed_requests
FROM issuedtickets JOIN completedtickets 
  ON (issuedtickets.week_number = completedtickets.week_number)
```

Also note that datepart(wk....) will be the same for all years. So you may need to add additional logic for years.

Comment: Remember sometimes the best thing to do is break down your query into smaller parts, and answer each part in order. Sometimes you can then go back and consolidate, but this way its easy to follow along.